# How to specify javax.xml.accessExternalSchema for the JAXB2 Maven plugin

Tags: java, maven, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I have a maven plugin (jaxb2) and I need to supply a jvm arg to it. I don't think there is a tag to add jvm args in the pom for it.

I know I can pass in jvm args on the command line eg: `mvn clean install -Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all`

Is it possible to set this jvm arg in the pom so that I don't have to type it into the command line every time?

(As aside - this jvm arg is required in order for it to work with JAVA-8. It works fine with JAVA-7)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This is relevant to the new [XML security properties in JAXB 1.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/properties/properties.html), introduced in Java 8. This is why your builds now fail on Java 8 but work with Java 7.

If you're using my `maven-jaxb2-plugin`, please upgrade to the version `0.9.0` or later (current is `0.10.0`). It has now a [`accessExternalSchema`](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/wiki/Configuring-Extension-Validation-and-XML-Security) switch (default is `all`).

This sets precisely `javax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all`.

Please see the [documentation](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/wiki/Configuring-Extension-Validation-and-XML-Security).

Comment: Thanks! Switching from the codehaus plugin to a recent version of yours solved the issue. No added config needed :)

Comment: In the documentation its mention that ACCESS_EXTERNAL_SCHEMA has default value of all, so why do we need to set it?

Comment: Neither this answer nor the documentation linked shows how to set the accessExternalSchema in the pom. The accessExternalSchema option is mentioned, but not clearly shown where it goes.

Answer (score 23):

I came across this issue while working with jaxb2-maven-plugin. I found a related jira issue for maven-jabx2-plugin - https://java.net/projects/maven-jaxb2-plugin/lists/issues/archive/2014-03/message/0

According to this issue Stephan202 suggested using properties-maven-plugin which worked like charm. Here is a sample code from his post -

```
<plugin>
<!-- We use this plugin to ensure that our usage of the
maven-jaxb2-plugin is JDK 8 compatible in absence of a fix
for https://java.net/jira/browse/MAVEN_JAXB2_PLUGIN-80. -->
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>set-additional-system-properties</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>set-system-properties</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <properties>
            <property>
                <name>javax.xml.accessExternalSchema</name>
                <value>file,http</value>
            </property>
        </properties>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: nice answer - thanks. I needed a solution that doesn't use alpha versions as that is my companies rules.

Comment: If you don't have truly external schemas, it can work to just the property to `file`. This is what I needed to get org.jvnet.ws.wadl:wadl-client-plugin:1.1.6 working with Java 8.

Comment: Thank God that I've found this answer after half a day of a fun!

Answer (score 9):

Re; the post - "I needed a solution that doesn't use alpha versions as that is my companies rules. –"

Changing the version to 1.0 & the value to 'all' got it working for me:

```
<plugin>
<!-- We use this plugin to ensure that our usage of the
maven-jaxb2-plugin is JDK 8 compatible in absence of a fix
for https://java.net/jira/browse/MAVEN_JAXB2_PLUGIN-80. -->
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <!--
    <version>1.0-alpha-2</version> -->
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>set-additional-system-properties</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>set-system-properties</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <properties>
            <property>
                <name>javax.xml.accessExternalSchema</name>
                <value>all</value>
            </property>
        </properties>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

It has worked for me :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>process-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsimport</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <vmArgs>
                    <arg>-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all</arg>
                </vmArgs>
                <keep>true</keep>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <wsdlDirectory>${project.build.directory}/wsdl</wsdlDirectory>
                <wsdlFiles>
                    <wsdlFile>ServiceWsService.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                </wsdlFiles>
                <bindingFiles>
                    <bindingFile>custom-binding.xml</bindingFile>
                    <bindingFile>custom-binding2.xml</bindingFile>
                </bindingFiles>                         
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Please explain why this works for you and why this helps the OP - don't just dump code.

Comment: OP was referring to JAXB2, not JAXWS.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Maven Compiler Plugin. Specifically you should be able to use the `<compilerArgument>` element to pass settings to the compiler.

See http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/pass-compiler-arguments.html for examples.

Comment: He's not trying to talk to the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to change the behavior of the JVM that is running Maven itself, add options to MAVEN_OPTS in the environment before launching mvn.

Comment: This is relevant to the new XML security properties in JAXB 1.5, introduced in Java 8, so it shouldn't actually be "Maven global" but rather just for schema compilation.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/properties/properties.html

Comment: Who knows if he has a Maven plugin, he uses your maven plugin, or he uses some other maven plugin?

Comment: @margulies I think the OP clearly stated that he *is* using one of the JAXB2 Maven plugins ("I have a maven plugin (jaxb2)...") and the tag suggests he uses mine. An note my answer has an "If ...".

Answer (score 0):

For `maven-jaxb2-plugin` version `2.5.0` trying to generate from `DTD` and spitting

> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: External parsing is disabled. Cannot
> parse URI: ...

it helped adding the following to plugin configuration

```
     <configuration>
         ...
         <externalEntityProcessing>true</externalEntityProcessing>
     </configuration>
```