# Add jvm options to maven plugin execution

Tags: java, maven, jaxb, maven-plugin

Is it possible to force any maven plugin to execute with VM arguments when I do `mvn clean install`?

**More context**
I have an old project that I try to mirgate to java 11. During this migration I had trouble with `wadl-client-plugin` and `JAXB` showing this error.

> schema_reference: Failed to read schema document '...', because 'file' access is not allowed due to restriction set by the accessExternalSchema property.

When I run it like `mvn clean install -Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all` it works. I need to include somehow `-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all` to the plugin execution when I run `mvn clean install`. I've checked  `wadl-client-plugin`'s docs and don't see anything about it. Is it possible to do it somehow in general way? Configuring local JVM is not an option neither as I cannot do it at all machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27823893/3457177)

`properties-maven-plugin` inside my `pom` did the trick.

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>set-additional-system-properties</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>set-system-properties</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <properties>
           <property>
                <name>javax.xml.accessExternalSchema</name>
                <value>all</value>
            </property>
        </properties>
        <outputFile/>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```